# Silverlight Navigation issues

Tags: silverlight, navigation

I am trying to navigate to pages passing parameters, which I have got to work from the mainpage, but when I try and do a similar thing at a lower level I get a page not found error (the index page works, but the DetailsIndex does not)

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                  <uriMapper:UriMapper x:Name="myUri">
                    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
                    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="DetailsIndex/{id}" MappedUri="/Views/DetailsIndex.xaml?id={id}"/>
                    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="Index/{id}" MappedUri="/Views/Index.xaml?id={id}"/>
                    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
                  </uriMapper:UriMapper>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs (this works)**

```
this.ContentFrame.Source = new Uri("/index?id=19", UriKind.Relative);
```

**IndexPage.xaml.cs (this gets a error -> Page not found: "DetailsIndex?id=66")**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            string id = btn.Tag.ToString();


        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("DetailsIndex?id={0}", id), UriKind.Relative));            
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be navigating using the Uri, not the mapped Uri.

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("DetailsIndex/{0}", id), UriKind.Relative));
```

Also, in the Uris in the mappings, I believe they usually start with a leading /.

Comment: thanks... It does work with the "/", I had some very weird behaviour where it was navigating to the page, and then the error was coming up when I used the navigationcontext... which threw me.

I am also debating using a singleton pattern instead of passing parameters this way... it seems a bit clunky

Answer (score 0):

After doing some investigation I found the below solution which worked for me

Xaml :

```
<uriMapper:UriMapper>
    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>                                      
</uriMapper:UriMapper>
```

Codebehind:

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HyperlinkButton hyp = sender as HyperlinkButton;
    string customer_id = hyp.Tag.ToString();
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/CustomerDetails?CustomerId=" + customer_id, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

This way I am able to pass the query string also

Comment: I'm a bit surprised... Using that pattern, you're asking for /Views/CustomersDetails?CustomId=1.xaml, which surely doesn't exist. Maybe I'm mistaken here, but I had this exact issue.